# Why entity_metadata_wrapper->save() doesn't update node's revision?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm developing a module to update nodes(enable revision). It looks like this.

```
 $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $bundleType));
 foreach ($ndoes as $node){
    $w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node);
    $w->MyFields->set($someValue);
    $w->save();
 }
```

It set fields correctly but node's revision-id didn't change after `$w->save()`.

How can I update the revision ID?

Comment: Is the `create new revision` flag set on the node for the content type? Have you tried like `$w->revision->set(1);` before saving? ....

Comment: Yes, "create new revision" is on. I don't know much about `$w->revision->set(1)`, is that a manual way to let the drupal knows that the node has been updated? I will try it.

Comment: hmm, `$w->revision->set()` works. It seems I misunderstand `$w->save()`. I thought it should increase the revision-id automatically while saving. Is there anyway to get next  increase revision id? Thank you

Comment: no, `revision->set(1)` tells the node to record a new revision on the upcoming/current edit of the node. I'm not sure why the metadata wrapper isn't seeing the global setting of create new revision ..... but setting the revision flag is a very simple workaround as you've now seen. I'm provided my comment as an answer below if you care to upvote it to help other users in the future find a correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the create new revision flag set on the node for the content type? Have you tried like $w->revision->set(1); before saving? ....

**EDIT:**

Author says setting `$w->revision->set(1)` solves his issue.

Comment: It's a easy workaround! Just don't understand why it's needed lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

When you edit a node via the UI, it is done via [`node_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7).  This has a call near the top to [`node_object_prepare()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7), which sets up default values for that node.  This includes setting the default value of `$node->revision`, which is used by [`node_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) to determine whether a new revision is needed or not.

The Entity API is revision aware, but `node_object_prepare()` is a node-specific thing.  This means that you need to manage the values yourself, including setting the revision property to mimic what the node edit form will do.

Answer (score 7):

None of these answers are actually correct, doing `->set(1)` makes it sound like your actually changing the revision number and therefore should increment it.

This is actually just a boolean flag so the correct answer is `$node->revision->set(true);`

As zhuchun says: he doesn't understand why its needed, when explained as a boolean flag it makes perfect sense rather than the number.

Comment: There was a time when creating new drupal content involved most easily calling `drupal_submit_form` for example. If you inspect the POST values for a node submit form you'll see things like `revision = 1` in the POST fields because the form items `create new revision` box was checked. Since `1 == TRUE` the code works either way. But, your point is valid.

Comment: this should be accepted answer

Comment: Also see: https://blog.arvixe.com/drupal7-entitymetadatawrapper-save-my-revision/

Answer (score 0):

If the node type doesn't have revisions enabled by default, the most succinct way to request a new revision is:

`$w->revision = TRUE;`

which is exactly the same as using:

`$w->revision->set(TRUE);`

but with less typing required.